# @command -v gpg why is the version flag before the command?

Tags: command-line, bash, make, makefile

```
verify:
    @command -v gpg 2>/dev/null || { echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

I saw the following command in a Makefile. I understand that it does the following:

1. `verify` is called before `build` in Makfile
2. `@command` is used to not echo the command being run and to not echo the output of the command which will be invoked
3. `-v gpg 2>/dev/null` will check the version and if gpg is not found it will redirect the error output(sterr) to null(nowhere)
4. `|| { echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."; exit 1; }` will echo a message and exit the current script with error 1 if the previous command creates an error (returns false which is why || is there)

What I don't understand is `-v gpg`. When checking the version the `-v` normally comes after the command. Is there a reason for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-v` is an argument for `command` builtin not for the `gpg`, it's not looking for "gpg" version, it's looking to see if any command named "gpg" exist.

From `help command`:

> ```
> -v    print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
> ```

it's similar to `type` builtin:

```
$ command -v gpg
/usr/bin/gpg
```

If it wasn't able to find the command, it'll return a non-zero exit status, so the "OR" section will be run:

```
|| { ... }
```

which will prints out:

```
Cound not find gpg. Aborting.
```

with an exit status code of "1".

Comment: Perfect explanation, ta!